# Azure Virtual Machine Login

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I started to try azure today, I am creating a windows 2016 virtual machine, everything is ok but i cant login with the username and password i created on the azure wizard, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try from the RDP you download from the connect button in the portal. You may want to connect as .\yourusername instead of just yourusername. You can also try resetting the password from the portal (portal.azure.com), reset remote access.

Comment: Works perfectly with ".\yourusername", thank you my friend for the super fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to login with the local administrator account? This allowed me to gain access to my VM, and once logged in I could change some settings.